# How to load separate html file into vue template instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue instance in a `.js` file, let's say `test.js`

```js
var vm= new Vue({
    el: '#app2',
    template: `
        <button @click="click2($event)">
            {{text}}
        </button>`,
    data: () => {
        return {
            text: "Hello"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        click2() {
            console.log("something")
        }
    }
})
```

I wonder if is there anyway I can put the `<button>` template into a separate `.html` file, lets say `test.html` and links that into the property `template`?

*Due to some constrains I cannot use vue-cli and webpack to generate `.vue` file`*

Thanks

Comment: You can separate template file like this: `template: require('./test.html')`

Comment: @Muhammadvakili Thanks!